# Eclipse: Can't Run As Maven Build with Workspace Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

m2eclipse behavior is driving me crazy and, after following a dozen of articles I feel like I'm loosing something. I'm using Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) and m2e plugin 1.7.0.20160303-1933.

I have a pretty simple project structure (actually it's more complex, but even the simplest one is not working) that looks like this:

```
 - project A
   - (dependes on) project B
```

Both projects are in the same Eclipse workspace. Both projects were imported as Maven projects.

Eclipse can solve the dependencies and show the projects as "OK" in the IDE (no errors), but if I try to Run As > Maven build (goal: compile) project A, maven fails saying that it could not find project B dependency.

I didn't install project B on my local repository, as I understand m2e can find them directly in the workspace and, thus, reflect any changes I made in the source code automatically. Is my assumption right? Or do I have to install all my projects before I can run it via Eclipse? It's would be very disappointing.

I have also tried to:

- disabling/enabling Maven nature on the projects again.. same result;
- mvn eclise:clean, refresh project, update maven project.. same
  result;
- checked all groupId, artifactId, version.. are all OK;
- removed and added the dependencies through Maven > Add Dep.. same result;
- checked in the POM view if the project is showing as an Eclipse project icon.. yes it is;

BTW, if I try to build (mvn compile) the project in the command line, I get the same error (but I see it as expected, as project A was not installed yet and maven (in the command line) doesn't know about my workspace. Am I wrong?

EDIT: my understanding comes from this [Sonatype link](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/eclipse.html) that states:

> You can configure a project to resolve dependencies from a workspace.
>   This has the effect of altering the way that Maven locates dependency
>   artifacts. **If a project is configured to resolve dependencies from the
>   workspace, these artifacts do not need to be present in your local
>   repository.**

Comment: The first test you should do is to try to run your whole project building with Maven on command line....If everything is fine than go back to Eclipse...

Comment: @khmarbaise if that's the way to go, what's m2e workspace dependency resolution utility?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, cause you need to check your build first on command line if your build is ok...or not...and them import it into Eclipse...BTW: Do not use `eclise:clean` etc. cause M2E will handle that better...

Comment: @khmarbaise I edited my question to make it more clear. My point is: Eclipse can use workspace projects as dependency, mvn in command line cannot.

Comment: The workspace resolution should work as you expect it to do. Make sure that the workspace resolution is not disabled (either globally or for the given project) and that group:artifact:version match exactly (including SNAPSHOT etc.). Furthermore, make sure that project B was build before you try to build project A.

Comment: @JFMeier group, artifact and version are OK and yes, I can build project B, but not project A (Run As > Maven Build) always fails cause it can't find project A. Is there a way I can debug where m2e is looking for dependencies?

Comment: If you open the Maven Dependencies directory in your project, do you see project B with a folder symbol?

Comment: @JFMeier yes, I do. I just removed everything from Eclipse and added again and I think it's working now. Really frustrating, but thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: i have exactly the same problem, but re-adding the projects did also not help

Comment: I solved my issue: Did you checked "Resolve Workspace artifacts" in the run configuration. This needs to be checked additionally to the general project setting about workspace resulution (at least for me here), but is never mentioned in tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all projects from Eclipse, added again and everything suddenly started working. Really frustrating.

I don't know if it is worth it to keep this question in SO, if some moderator judges it's better to delete this question I would see no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

The real solution to this problem (which had bothered me for so long) is a checkbox in the run dialog. You have to check `Resolve Workspace artifacts`. You have to do this every time despite your workspace settings.

[image]